# Standard library naming convention: Why is the counterpart of std::search called std::find_end?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I was looking at the [different algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) for finding/searching in the standard library and was wondering about the strange naming conventions used.

In particular the distinction between the family of search and find algorithms.
For example: `std::search` searches for the first occurrence of a subrange in the input range. In order to find the last occurrence instead, you can use `std::find_end`.
Why is find_end not called `search_end`? (or `search_last`).

Furthermore:
With the exception of `find_end`, all find* algorithms (`find`, `find_if`, `find_if_not`, `find_first_of`) look for a single value, whereas the search algorithms look for multiple values (`search`, `search_n`). To me this seems like another reason why find_end should be called `search_end`/`search_last`.

Is there some historical reason for un-intuitive naming of `find_end`? or is there something else I'm overlooking?

Comment: I think it is still consistent, find_end still returns ONE result (which is a range of items). Where all search methods can return multiple matches.

Comment: Search only returns a single iterator. Sure, you can then invoke search a second time to see if there are more occurrences of the range, but it is still only one result per invocation.

Comment: Naming things is one of the two hard problems in computer programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason: the algorithms are different.

`search` moves forward by the interval and searches the first occurrence.

`find_end` also moves forward by the interval and finds the last of all occurrences. It uses `search` and returns the last positive result.

Literally, *finding* is the completion of *searching*.

Comment: Interesting way to look at it. But if we say finding is the completion of searching, shouldn't std::find then also be called std::search? (and maybe std::search should be called search_range). After all, std::find also returns the first result

Comment: No, it could not. `find` could be confusing, it implies searching something existing: you find an apple in the fridge. `search` may result in failure: search food in the fridge, if you find it, then eat it. `find_last` - finds between consecutive `search` results. It's obvious, at least one result exists (maybe negative).

Comment: I like the analogy, but don't think it fits here. If I use `search` on a container that contains the subrange it "finds it" and returns an iterator. On a container that does not contain the subrange, it does not find it and returns the end iterator. 
Similarly, if I use `find_end` on a container that contains the subrange, it finds (the last) one and returns it. On a container that does not contain the subrange, it does not find it and returns the end iterator. 
I know `find_end` is implemented using a search, but that is an implementation detail and should not be motivation for the name.

Comment: I do not get your aim. You asked the question. I assumed you was expecting an answer. I answered. Why do you argue?

Comment: I'm not trying to argue, just trying to get more insight into your answer. (I think it is the best answer I heard, just want to fully understand it)